# Actual maximum resolution and refresh rate of Samsung JU6500?

Tags: hdmi, amd-radeon, hdtv, high-definition

I just got a Samsung UN40 JU6500 and plugged it into an active `Displayport -> HDMI` adapter using a high speed HDMI 1.4 cable.

I am running it at the maximum possible 3840x2160 @ 30Hz on my **Radeon 5770** card, but the Radeon settings is reporting that it can go up to 4096x2160 @ 75Hz?

[image: max reported resolution]

I assume that my card is too old to produce that resolution. However in reading online, users are only able to push the display to 3840x2160 @ 60Hz.

Before I choose a proper card to upgrade to, can anyone shed some light on whether the reported resolution and Hz are correct, or if I should just shoot for the 60Hz and forget pushing 75Hz?

### Solution/Update

Thanks to **kobaltz** below for showing me where to find "List All Modes" that pairs the resolutions with the refresh rates possible!

[image]

It turns out I had the monitor plugged into a crappy "Displayport to HDMI" device that was not capable of going past 30Hz! Unplugging from there and plugging directly into the HDMI port (on a newer-gen graphics card) resulted in wonderful 60Hz refresh rate. Problem solved.

Comment: I'm slightly confused on how/where these Radeon settings are getting this information? The TV that you got has a 4K UHD `3840x2160` resolution and a refresh rate of 120 Hz. I don't know where it's getting the resolution and the refresh rate from.

Comment: @DrZoo Of course it doesn’t actually do 120 Hz. That’s just the interpolation rate (or “motion rate”, as Samsung calls it). The information is provided as part of the [EDID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Display_Identification_Data).

Comment: @DrZoo just like hard drives have a "max throughput" that is never achievable in the real world, monitors/TVs have resolutions and refresh rates that are the maximum possible but not achievable. It's all marketing.

Comment: That’s also not true, @degenerate. If it couldn’t be used, there’d be legal conflict sooner or later. What’s in the specs is achievable. Otherwise it’s a scam.

Comment: @DanielB you are correct. I plugged the TV into a different graphics card and it was able to get 60Hz at the desired resolution. I updated my post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum supported refresh rate does not necessarily mean at the maximum resolution. Chances are, the resolution supported at that refresh rate would be really low.

[image]

You can try to list the modes of supported resolutions and refresh rates to see what is the maximum resolution at the highest possible refresh rate.